# Shuffling parts of a file between markers

Tags: bash, awk, shuffle

I have files that look like this:

```
asdasadsdasdas
dasdasdasdasd
asdas
dasd
asdas
das
das
das
das
das
#SHUFFLE_MARK_START
das
d
das
das
dasd
asd
asdas
das
das
afs
sf
#SHUFFLE_MARK_END
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
```

I want to shuffle only part of file between two markers - `#SHUFFLE_MARK_START` and `#SHUFFLE_MARK_END`, shuffle markers can be any string I want, they just need to be unique filewise, any ideas how to do it in bash so it's efficient?

I already tried to do it by doing something like

```
cat file | grep -P '.+#SHUFFLE_MARK_START' > start
cat file | grep -P '#SHUFFLE_MARK_START.+#SHUFFLE_MARK_FINISH' | shuff | > middle
cat file | grep -P '#SHUFFLE_MARK_FINISH.+' > end
echo start middle end > shuffled
```

but it's pretty slow for big files, commands above may be slightly wrong as I'm typing them from memory just to show idea

Comment: Is there only one set of markers in the file?

Comment: @Shawn they can be literally any string I imagine, they're not certainly exactly `#SHUFFLE_MARK_START`, I'm just creating unique ones so that they're not confused with normal lines in file, and no, there can be few sections with shuffle markers, but if that's problem I can enumerate them like `section1start`, `section2start`, that's not an issue

Comment: also sections cannot overlap/nest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a perl script that does it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage: foo.pl input.txt > output.txt
# or
# foo.pl < input.txt > output.txt
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw/shuffle/;
my $in_block = 0;
my @lines;
while (<>) {
  if (/#SHUFFLE_MARK_START/) {
    print;
    $in_block = 1;
  } elsif (/#SHUFFLE_MARK_END/) {
    print shuffle(@lines);
    print;
    $in_block = 0;
    @lines = ();
  } elsif ($in_block == 0) {
    print;
  } else {
    push @lines, $_;
  }
}
```

(If you don't want to include the #SHUFFLE_MARK_START etc lines, remove the appropriate `print;` lines)

Comment: love the perl solution, definitely will use it, it's gonna be pretty nice to automate my workflow, thanks!

Comment: That may be the first clearly written perl script I've ever seen! I don't think I've ever upvoted a perl script before as I could never tell what they were actually doing so here's another first - +1!

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue! assumes unique markers

```
$ awk '/#SHUFFLE_MARK_END/   {c++} 
                             {print > (FILENAME "." c+0)} 
       /#SHUFFLE_MARK_START/ {c++}' file
$ cat file.0 <(shuf file.1) file.2 > file.shuffled
```

difficult to see in the random file, here is a test script as well

```
$ seq 20 | sed 's/11/#SHUFFLE_MARK_START/;s/16/#SHUFFLE_MARK_END/' > file
$ awk ...
$ cat file.0 <(shuf file.1) file.2

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
#SHUFFLE_MARK_START
14
15
13
12
#SHUFFLE_MARK_END
17
18
19
20
```

**UPDATE**

here is a combined `awk` script, without intermediate files

```
$ awk '/#SHUFFLE_MARK_END/   {c++; close("shuf")} 
                             {if(c%2) print | "shuf"; else print}
       /#SHUFFLE_MARK_START/ {c++}' file
```

which will handle multiple (non-intersecting) sections

for this test file

```
$ seq 20 | sed -E 's/1?3/#SHUFFLE_MARK_START/;s/1?7/#SHUFFLE_MARK_END/' > file

$ awk ... file

1
2
#SHUFFLE_MARK_START
5
6
4
#SHUFFLE_MARK_END
8
9
10
11
12
#SHUFFLE_MARK_START
14
16
15
#SHUFFLE_MARK_END
18
19
20
```

Comment: Just need to automate the cat/shuf bit to handle shuffling multiple sections in the same file.

Comment: this answer is nice too, that's exactly what I wanted to get in answer, simple console commands to achieve my tarrget, but I think perl script would be easier to automate and adapt for multiple tags

Comment: @stetoc No problem, please check the updated version as well.

Comment: I don;t think that's guaranteed to output the lines in the order you expect since the process that "shuf" is running in might not finish producing output til after the process awk is running in produces it's next line(s) of output after calling close("shuf"). The close() is just closing the pipe to "shuf" and then shuf could still read any buffered input and output any buffered output. I could be wrong but I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: To test my theory I just tried the above script (the one without intermediate files of course) with 1 million lines between the START and END tags and I did get some of the shuffled lines being output after the END tag. As expected, that didn't happen with the co-process approach in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53093499/1745001).

Comment: I thought **close("shuf")** will wait for the process to complete, but don't know for sure.

Comment: Apparently not since I did see shuf output after the close(). I just put the output of `seq 1000000` between the START and END tags to test it.

Comment: You get this same effect when you call `system(cmd)` btw - the `cmd` output doesn't necessarily appear before the next line of awk output.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for co-processes and the UNIX "shuf" command:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { shuf="shuf" }
/^#SHUFFLE_MARK_END/ {
    close(shuf, "to")
    while ( (shuf |& getline line) > 0 ) {
        print line
    }
    close(shuf)
    inShuf=0
}
inShuf  { print |& shuf }
!inShuf { print }
/^#SHUFFLE_MARK_START/ { inShuf=1 }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
asdasadsdasdas
dasdasdasdasd
asdas
dasd
asdas
das
das
das
das
das
#SHUFFLE_MARK_START
sf
das
asdas
dasd
das
d
das
das
afs
das
asd
#SHUFFLE_MARK_END
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
fas
```